# How to set authDomain when using init.js

Tags: javascript, firebase

I am using the auto SDK URLs to initialize Firebase:

```
<script src="/__/firebase/6.1.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="/__/firebase/6.1.1/firebase-auth.js"></script>
<script src="/__/firebase/6.1.1/firebase-storage.js"></script>
<script src="/__/firebase/6.1.1/firebase-messaging.js"></script>
<script src="/__/firebase/6.1.1/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
<script src="/__/firebase/init.js"></script>
```

I need to set the authDomain to my business domain which is set up on Firebase so that the Google gmail authentication shows my domain name and not my firebase project name.

Do I have to stop using these URLs and instead construct a config and initialize Firebase manually? Or is there a way to update authDomain separately?

I tried the following to see if I could get the config settings and then I planned to modify the authDomain. I received an error instead.

```
<script>
fetch('/__/firebase/init.json').then(async response => {
  firebase.initializeApp(await response.json());
});
</script>
```

Here is the error from the developer log:

> (index):195 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to execute 'json' on 'Response': body stream is locked
>      at (index):195
>   (anonymous) @ (index):195
>   errors.ts:137 Overwriting FirebaseError base field "name" can cause unexpected behavior.

[UPDATE}
Seems that fetch is asynchronous and that all the scripts load asynchronously as well. Bottom line its darn near impossible to get the config information programmatically, change authDomain and then call initializeApp before loading my framework scripts and initializing my main app which relies on firebase already being there.

Here is the async version i tried:

```
await fetch('/__/firebase/init.json').then(async (response)=> {
    let config = await response.json();
    config[authDomain] = 'mydomain.com';
    await firebase.initializeApp(config);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use this, you just need to wait for the `fetch()` promise to resolve before attempting to do anything with Firebase.

For example

```js
const firebaseReady = fetch('/__/firebase/init.json')
  .then(res => res.ok ? res.json() : Promise.reject(res))
  .then(config => {
    // do whatever you need to do with config
    return firebase.initializeApp(config)
  })
```

Now you just need to chain on to the `firebaseReady` promise. For example

```js
firebaseReady.then(app => {
  const db = app.firestore()
  const auth = app.auth()

  // do other things here
})
```

Comment: There is still the problem of loading my framework, app js and third party scripts. If I have to do all those inside the firebaseReady call then I have to manually fetch all my remaining scripts which seems awkward.
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/framework7@4.5.0/js/framework7.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/cloudinary-core@2.7.4/cloudinary-core-shrinkwrap.min.js"></script>
  
  <script src="js/routes.js"></script>
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>

Comment: Actually the first two of my loaded scripts can be loaded before the firebase app initialization so its just my local app scripts that would need to be fetched. Still seems odd.